# Display name of tag on tag page

Tags: feature-request, tags

When I view a tag page, e.g.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css

there is no mention on that page of the tag name ("CSS"). Although, in the most common use-case of following a clearly labelled tag link, this is not a huge problem, there are several other cases in which it could cause confusion:

- Following an external link
- Returning to the page some time later
- Accidentally clicking the wrong tag link

I think that, especially with the inclusion of the 'mini tag wiki' at the top of a tag's page, it would make an awful lot of sense to display the name of the tag (either as a level-2 heading or as a suffix to the existing "Tagged Questions" h1).

Answer (score 2):

Well' it is there, but it could be more prominent. Obviously, when the tag wiki is displayed, there is a single tag searched and therefore no problem adding it to the title (or the wiki box, which would make the wiki box more intrusive though).

[image]

But imaging searching many tags - like delphi*, which extends to this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure exactly how to handle multiple tags (your example, in particular, is a tricky one - /almost/ want a 'delphi' heading ...) but I think for the simplest case, single tag, displaying the tag name makes a lot of sense